# 301 redirects within Laravel 4

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I have built a new website in Laravel 4 that will replace an old site built using basic html pages. When I go live, I need to redirect old pages to the new structure.

i.e. website.co.uk/ourpolicy.html     to    website.co.uk/ourpolicy

I would normally do this in the .htaccess file for a non Laravel project.

My current .htaccess:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Would I just add my rewrite like this to htaccess or is there a better way in Laravel?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    redirect 301 /ourpolicy.html http://www.website.co.uk/ourpolicy

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic rule to strip `.html` from URLs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^business-london\.html$ /london/business [L,NC,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer, yes, that would work in my simple example, but some pages will be different, for example business-london.html will become london/business

Comment: Those specific rules need to be added before generic html redirect rule (see updated rule)